# How does the "creation phase" know how much memory space to set up?

Tags: javascript

In [JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts](https://youtu.be/Bv_5Zv5c-Ts) the instructor explains that memory for variables is set up during a so-called creation phase (and that `undefined`  is assigned); then the execution phase happens. But why is this useful when we don't know what value(s) the variable will later point to?

Clearly variables can point to many different things -from e.g. a short string all the way to a deeply nested object structure -and I assume that they can vary wildly in the amount of memory they need.

If line-by-line execution -including variable assignment -happens only in the later, execution phase, how can the initial creation phase know how to set up memory? Or, is memory set aside only for the name in each variable name/value pair, with memory for the value being managed differently?

Answer (score 5):

The instructor is referring to [Google Chrome's V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/v8/intro) (as is evidenced by his use of it in the video).

The V8 engine uses several optimization approaches in order to facilitate memory management. At first, it will compile the JavaScript code and during compilation it will determine how many variables (hidden classes, more later) it needs to create. These will determine the amount of memory originally allocated.

> V8 compiles JavaScript source code directly into machine code when it is first executed. There are no intermediate byte codes, no interpreter. Property access is handled by inline cache code that may be patched with other machine instructions as V8 executes. <sup>**1**</sup>

The first set is created by navigating the JavaScript code to determine how many different object "shapes" there are. Anything without a prototype is considered to be a "Transitioning object shape"

> The main way objects are encoded is by separating the hidden class (description) from the object (content). When new objects are instantiated, they are created using the same initial hidden class as previous objects from the same constructor. As properties are added, objects transition from hidden class to hidden class, typically following previous transitions in the so-called “transition tree”. <sup>**2**</sup>

Conversely, if the object *does* have a prototype then it will have its particular shape tracked separately.

> Prototypes have 2 main phases: *setup* and *use*. Prototypes in the setup phase are encoded as dictionary objects. Any direct access to the prototype, or access through a prototype chain, will transition it to *use state*, making sure that all such accesses from now on are fast. <sup>**2**</sup>

The compiler will essentially read all possible variables as being one of these two possible shapes and then allocate the amount of memory necessary to facilitate instantiating those shapes.

Once the first set of shapes is setup, V8 will then take advantage of what they call "fast property access" in order to build on the first set of variables (hidden classes) that were setup during the build.

> To reduce the time required to access JavaScript properties V8 dynamically creates hidden classes behind the scenes <sup>**3**</sup>
>
> There are two advantages to using hidden classes: property access does not require a dictionary lookup, and they enable V8 to use the classic class-based optimization, inline caching <sup>**3**</sup>

As a result, not all memory use is known during compilation, only how much to allocate for the core set of hidden classes. This allocation will grow as the code is executed, from things like assignment, inline cache misses, and conversion into dictionary mode (which happens when too many properties are assigned to an object, and several other nuanced factors).

---

*<sub>1. Dynamic machine code generation, https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Design%20Elements#dynamic-machine-code-generation</sub>

<sub>2. Setting up prototypes in V8, https://medium.com/@tverwaes/setting-up-prototypes-in-v8-ec9c9491dfe2</sub>

<sub>3. Fast Property Access, https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Design%20Elements#fast-property-access</sub>*

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is a bit of a problem you know at least in my opinion

in Javascript there are specifications of the language made by ecmascript
and there are implementation made by developers

you have to understand that what is been taught about Javascript what's so called "under the hood" are the specifications of Javascript

you might have heard the terms **Execution Context** **Lexical Environment**.

They are only spec on how the language should work they give idea to the Developers how to build their JS engine in a way that it will **behave** like the spec.

> An execution context is purely a specification mechanism and need not correspond to any particular artefact of an ECMAScript implementation. It is impossible for ECMAScript code to directly access or observe an execution context. ECMAScript

Every Javascript engine is implemented differently and they supposed to behave like the spec of ECMAScript

there is a concept that everytime when an execution context is created.
it has stages creation phase and execution phase.

everytime when creation phase begin it's allocating memory for the variables for that execution context.

in reality it doesn't work like that at all
there is no really a "Creation Phase" at least in V8 engine(Google Chrome JS Engine) in the way that you think.

i can give you a hint and tell you that eveytime when you call a function that
doesn't have another function inside it.

the variables inside that function are basically replacing some "block" in memory

i will give you a basic example let's say V8 engine uses some address in memory
let's say the address is 0x61FF1C

`function setNum(){ var num = 5; }`

everytime when i will call the setNum function the value for example of `num` will get stored at address `0x61FF1C` EVERYTIME when i will call the function the value of `num 5`it will get stored at 0x61FF1C so it's overwriting the content that were before inside 0x61FF1C.

that's just how the v8 engine works in that scenario now the example i gave is just to get the idea i know it's sounds a little vague.

there is much more to the V8 engine which i'm not going to discuss because it's huge
by the way i'm not a V8 developer so i dont know everything about that engine
i'm not even close to that level but i know some things.

anyway i think that every JS Developer should think in the spec way but also remember that many engines **behave** like the spec but it doesn't mean that they **work** exactly like the spec

Answer (score 0):

When any program executes, time of execution we call running time.  During running time or processing time, processor process code and communicate with memory. Procesor takes code from memory, process it, result give back to memory, take other code. All the running time, some space in memory get grater; some space gets zero, some variables get the new value,  some variables have been deleting, etc. Volume of working memory in running time is changing all the time.